# ubuntu 14.04 getting freezeed

Tags: 14.04

I have installed ubuntu 14.04 on laptop (toshiba setellite c) with core i3, 2gb ram.
Please give me solution on this or suggest any other best version.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Lubuntu. It based on Ubuntu but using LXDE (desktop environment). LXDE have low-system-requirement for older PC and laptop with low RAM like you laptop.

Comment: I love ubuntu and i am comfortable it, please suggest me any other ubuntu version.